# Compiling with SDL in different directories

Tags: c, sdl-2

I'm trying to do a project which uses SDL2 to do the graphics.
I want to have my project files in a directory.
I have the functions that manipulate the SDL directly and pictures in a subdirectory of this (UI_library).

I solved the compiling part by adding to the compilation commands

```
-LUI_library
```

The problem is that when I run the program, it can't find the pictures, since it assumes they are in the project directory and not in the subdirectory.

Do you know how to fix this without manually changing the code in the subdirectory? There are a lot of references to the pictures in the library.

Comment: Use `chdir()` from `unistd.h`.

Comment: Do you know how to do it from the command line?

Comment: You can `cd` to the directory where the images are, and then run your exe from here. Or you can, in your code, `chdir` to the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem would be addressing the whole path to your file.

For Example:

Windos:
`SDL_LoadBMP("C:\Documents\your_image.bmp")`

Linux:
`SDL_LoadBMP("/home/tigre200/Documents/your_image.bmp")`